# How can I create undeletable notifications?

Tags: java, android, notifications

this is my source code. I need, to make it undeletable - it should be delete after click on that, not by swiping in the notification manager. Is it possible?

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("NotiClick", true);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        Notification Noti;
        Noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Dont Lose It")
                .setContentText("Stop monitoring by click!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, Noti);
    }`
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [setOngoing(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)) with your `Notification.Builder`:

> Set whether this is an "ongoing" notification. Ongoing notifications cannot be dismissed by the user, so your application or service must take care of canceling them. They are typically used to indicate a background task that the user is actively engaged with (e.g., playing music) or is pending in some way and therefore occupying the device (e.g., a file download, sync operation, active network connection).

Comment: And how can I delete it after click? Because now it is still undeletable.. :-/

Comment: Hello, you just have to set the boolean or the variable in the event click to false.